# How to call a piece of code only after a callback function has been executed?

Tags: javascript

Consider this code, just like a toy example:

```
function loadDoc() {

    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {

        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = this.responseText;
        }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", "demo_get2.asp?fname=Henry&lname=Ford", true);
    xhttp.send();
}
```

Let's consider that there are five kinds of asynchronous calls inside the function `loadDoc()`. What I want to do is now is to call another function or any piece of code when all five callback functions are executed. Does Javascript provide anything to help with this situation, or we need to set a flag to check if all 5 tasks are executed?

Comment: Lots of suggestions here: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+wait+multiple+ajax+-%5Bjquery%5D

Answer (score 2):

If you use [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) you'll be able to use `Promise.all([promises])`.

"Promisifying" your current ajax request:

```
function loadDoc() {
    req().then(function (responseText) {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = responseText;
    })

}

function req () {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {

            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                resolve(this.responseText);
            } else {
                reject();
            }
        };
        xhttp.open("GET", "demo_get2.asp?fname=Henry&lname=Ford", true);
        xhttp.send();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either use a callback or a promise,

callback example:

```
function loadDoc(cb) {

  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {

    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = this.responseText;
        cb(xhttp.responseText); // <= run the callback
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "demo_get2.asp?fname=Henry&lname=Ford", true);
  xhttp.send();

}

loadDoc(function(res) {
  console.log(res);
  // do something 
});
```

promise example:

```
function loadDoc(cb) {
  return return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {

      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = this.responseText;
        resolve(xhttp.responseText); // <= run the callback
      } else {
        reject(xhttp.responseText);
      }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", "demo_get2.asp?fname=Henry&lname=Ford", true);
    xhttp.send();

}

loadDoc()
.then(function(res) {
  console.log(res);
  // do something 
})
.catch(function(err) {
  console.error(err);
  // do something 
});
```

Comment: The callback must not be called at the bottom of `loadDoc`, it's then useless. It should be called inside the callback of `onreadystatechange`.